# short view distance in 3d view?

Tags: 3d-view

Ok so In blender, I'm making a city, but in the 3d view, it disappears when going to a certain distance:
[image: Falls off after a certain point]
I'm not using a camera or anything, this is user perspective
Help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The farthest distance the viewport can see is called the *far clipping pane*, there is also a *near clipping pane* that clips anything closer than a specified distance.  On the strip on the right of the 3d view (if it is not there you can hit the + at the top right corner of the view) you can adjust the *far clipping pane* spinner.  The clipping panes of the camera (if you will be needing to do some zoomed out renders) are under the *camera* panel in the *properties* view when the camera is selected.

Answer (score 16):

Try increasing the *clipping end* distance in *3D view > right side vertical panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) > View > Clip End*:

[image]

For Blender 2.79 and previous *3D View > Properties Region (<kbd>N</kbd>) > View > Clip*:

[image]

Comment: Sorry gandalf3, I didn't copy your answer, I hit the post button on mine just as your answer popped up!

Comment: @PGmath lol, happens all the time.. no worries. :) On the plus side, now there are two answers (and two is always better than one?) On the other hand, I think I just found a duplicate question anyway..

Comment: Where is this in Blender 4? There's no View button there. :(