# Is there a render DEPTH limit?

Tags: rendering

I have a tall object, casting a (sun lamp) shadow onto a plane scaled at 10,000 (dimensions 20K x 20K). But the shadow is being cut off not far behind my object (I can also see this visible limit in OGL). No matter how large I scale the ground object, the shadow is always cut off at the same place. If I view from top, the entire shadow is there! [image: Top view] Changing Camera > View > Clipping Start and End has NO effect. So why is the depth being cut off in my OGL and renders? [image: Render view]

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is!
Select your camera and in `camera` tab, you can see `clipping` section.
Set the `End` to whatever you need, but not more (more number makes it harder for you computer to render)

Comment: I already tried that, and it does nothing. According to what I read in the manual, it "should" solve the problem. So I must be missing something.

Comment: @DrStrik9 note there are two limits; [one for the render and camera view, and one for the general 3D view](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39340/599). If neither one solves it, is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: The only clip settings (start & end) I know of are in the "N" screen when the camera is selected. Where is the other one?

Comment: @Gandalf3 I found the Display and View Panels in the Manual, but it doesn't say WHERE they are located, or how to access them in Blender.

Comment: @DrStrik9 Does [this answer help?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5202/599)

Comment: @Gandalf3 That was IT! Thank you so much.