# Far away things (skybox cube) not showing up?

Tags: animation, camera

When making a little animation thing, I ran into a problem, the camera could not see the entire skybox. (a large cube with textures on it) As in the camera would not render the entire box.
Here is a picture:
[image]

Can anybody help me? Essentially I want the camera to be able to see further.

Comment: Looks like a clipping problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417194/why-blender-rendering-objects-to-block-cut-each-other-and-how-to-avoid-it/36424270#36424270

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/short-view-distance-in-3d-view/16583#16583

Comment: So, it was a clipping problem, thanks DrRiisTab.