# How do I prevent planes from partially disappearing when zooming out?

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

I'm trying to create a Minecraft animation in blender and I figured how to create models, UV map, and texture them, but whenever I zoom out you can see through planes partially. How would I fix this?

in 3D view(material view): [image]

in 3D view(rendered view): [image]

Comment: adjust the clip distance for the viewport

Comment: possible duplicates: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/8554#8554 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/short-view-distance-in-3d-view/16583#16583 and  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Comment: I already tried that and it's not my problem

Comment: Then you should describe your problem better. And use screenshots that really tells something. Nobody understands what your problem is at the moment.