# Layout view, can't see my model

Tags: modeling

I modeled the city scape. I pressed something and all I can see now is half of the model.

[image: 1]]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [short view distance in 3d view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/short-view-distance-in-3d-view) and [Where can the viewport clipping parameters be changed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed)

Answer (score 1):

That's the 3D view clip. I'm not sure why it is there, but you can resize your mesh/object and it will be fine. Or, you can press "N" to open up that right window and adjust the clip size to stop cutting through your object.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes, thank you! that help a lot!